# How To Find Difference Of Two Pointer Values

Tags: c, pointers, subtraction

I am learning C programming and currently on Pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void update(int *a,int *b) {
        *a = *a + *b;
        //*b = *a - *b;
        printf("%d", *a - *b);

}

int main() {
    int a = 4, b = 5;
    int *pa = &a, *pb = &b;
    
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    update(pa, pb);
 
    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why it prints 4 instead of -1. I want to assign their difference in pointer *b. Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: You are learning `c`, but you are writing in `c++`.

Comment: @KfirVentura oh my bad

Comment: I removed the c tag and replaced it with c++ at the same time as you edited the code, so you might wanna fix that too

Comment: The `scanf()` call is going to overwrite the values of `a` and `b` with whatever integers you entered into stdin when you ran the program; so without knowing what you entered when you ran the program, it's impossible to say why the program prints 4 instead of -1.

Comment: **Read the documentation of your C compiler** (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org), to be used as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **read the documentation of your debugger** (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...) and **use the debugger**; read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: **Take inspiration from the source code of *existing* open source C programs**, like  [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or other programs (e.g. on https://github.com/ ....)

Comment: Later, look into some C standard document like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case,

```
    *a = *a + *b;
    cout << *a - *b;
```

adds the value of `*b` to `*a`, and then subtract `*b`, so it's essentially the same as

```
    cout << *a + *b -*b;
```

or

```
    cout << *a;
```

which is `4` (assuming you entered the same value with which you initialized the variables in the code).

Comment: @unobatbayar It's not a computation issue, it's a mathematical one.

Comment: After your answer, this worked  *b = *a - *b - *b;

Comment: The question is about C, and your answer is for C++

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The original question was mistakenly written in `c++`.

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand.

Answer (score 2):

> I have no idea why it prints 4 instead of -1.

Well, strictly speaking the code can't be said to print 4. Nor -1.

The code will print the first (integer) value that you type in the console (due to the `scanf` statement).

Your function alters `a` by adding `b`. But when you call `printf` you again subtract `b` so you print the **original** value of `a` which is the first input for the `scanf`.

> I want to assign their difference in pointer *b

Well, then replace:

```
    *a = *a + *b;
    //*b = *a - *b;
```

with

```
    //*a = *a + *b;
    *b = *a - *b;
```

Now `b` contains the difference between the values read by `scanf`. To print it simply do:

```
printf("difference between scan'ed values: %d", *b);
```

BTW: For good coding style do this change:

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b); --> if(scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) != 2) exit(1);
```

also notice that functionally this is the same as:

```
if(scanf("%d %d", pa, pb) != 2) exit(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use conversion syntax:

```
int value;
value = (int)(*a) - (int)(*b);
printf(value);
```

this should do the trick. but if you'd like to get absolute value, then you'll need an IF-ELSE statements, like so:

```
int value;
if(*a > *b)
    value = (int)(*a) - (int)(*b);
else
    value = (int)(*b) - (int)(*a);

printf(value);
```

Comment: Why all the casting?

Comment: question's title has changed, i guess. my bad.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it's giving me SIGSEGV error

Comment: `printf(value);` -> don't take this literally.

Comment: in which line you are getting this error? @unobatbayar

Comment: This gives me 1 instead of -1, but why does assigning to an integer makes it 1 while assigning to a pointer value makes it 4? they do the calculation differently?

Comment: question's title has been edited, I do update it right now

Comment: @attirant now it works perfectly. If you have time, please explain why? I highly value your reply.

Comment: I'm not certain about this, ever since I'm writing c/c++ in CodeBlocks, its compiler really contains bugs in using pointers. I guessed you might be facing this, maybe.

Comment: You should be using `uintptr_t`, not `int`. There's no guarantee that `int` is the right size. (Isn't it the wrong size in Windows + x64?)

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to Simulate by Reference your invoking the function wrong in update(pa, pb);

By calling update you are running that function you just need to re-assign the "updated" values back to the original value location like this: update(&a, &b);

Once you have updated the values print value a and you'll have -1